# Get reference to the stdin file descriptor on OS X?

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, pid

On a Linux machine, if I have the pid of a process, I can write to the stdin of that process using something like:

```
/proc/<pid>/fd/0
```

but on MacOS, this doesn't appear possible. I am told that I should use `mkfifo` / named pipes.

However using named pipes is making the problem harder to solve. Is there a way on MacOS to store a reference to a fd on the filesystem if you control the start of the process?

For example, if I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
node script.js &
NODEJS_PID=$!
```

I can easily get the pid of this process, represented above by the NODEJS_PID var. However, is there a way to capture a reference to the file descriptor of the stdin to this nodejs process?

If I can get the path to the fd that would be cool, because I need to write to that fd from another process altogether.

Comment: You would be better off stating what you are actually trying to do before dismissing a named pipe as a solution.

Comment: Just call `mkfifo` using any name you please. What is difficult about that? How about just using `mktemp` to get a name you can use? I strongly suspect you have a misunderstanding about what you can do on Linux. You would still have to create something to be the standard input before you launch the process. You can find it later, but you have to make the it in the first place somehow.

Comment: named pipes make what I am trying to do trickier, explaining why it's trickier is out of the scope of the question. if there is no way to do what I describe in the question, that's fine.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do, they make it easier. If you try to use the method you are talking about, what makes you think you'll get a descriptor that's writable?! Remember, you grabbed the process's **input** descriptor which may or may not be the one you write to if you want something to come out there.

Comment: I believe the stdin fd would always be writable, if I control the process.

Comment: I already tried the named piped method, it probably can be done, but it's just harder to do, from what I can tell.

Comment: Can you update your question explaining how the process gets created? Because without knowing that, we don't know what you're actually working on. Are you creating it with a named pipe for its standard input? Because, if so, typically the input end is *not* writable.

Comment: I am happy to answer that, although it would take significant effort. Frankly, I find it hard to believe that it is impossible to get the stdin file descriptor of a process that I just started. I have the pid, why can't I store a reference to its stdin?

Comment: You probably can, depending on how you're creating the process.

Comment: I just showed in the question how I create the process. Let's use that as the example to work with.

Comment: You mean the "for example" code? That doesn't give the process a stdin that's writable.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What do you think the `stdin` of that script will be if you launch it like that? You're not creating anything that you can put data into and get data out of. In any event, this is clearly an XY problem. You are asking about something you think will solve your problem without really telling us exactly what your problem actually is.

Comment: But that makes some sense now that I think about it.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that you could write directly to the stdin of the node.js process instead of using some buffer, like a fifo.

Comment: What you're missing is that the stdin has to be a reference to something. A pipe, a virtual terminal, a socket, ... something. And most of things have two ends, one you put things in and one stuff comes out of. You don't stuff things in the output end.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and that makes sense. *However* I thought when you start a process, it almost always has some fd pre-dedicated that can handle its stdin. and you write to that fd. right?

Comment: for example, you start the background node.js process like I did in the example. you have the pid. then on a linux machine, you could take the pid and get the stdin file descriptor via /proc/<pid>/fd/0....then from there, you can use that fd to write to stdin.